# Creating a table using a button in C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I tried this code and nothing is added or created.

I didn't get any errors or bugs, it just add nothing..

Code:

```
private void simpleButton1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC; Initial Catalog=StudentDB; Integrated Security=True;");
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + txtName.Text + " (LRN int, FirstName nvarchar(50), MiddleName nvarchar(50), LastName nvarchar(50), Gendernvarchar(50), " + txtSub1.Text + " nvarchar(50), " + txtSub2.Text + " nvarchar(50), " + txtSub3.Text + " nvarchar(50), " + txtSub4.Text + " nvarchar(50), " + txtSub5.Text + " nvarchar(50), " + txtSub6.Text + " nvarchar(50), " + txtSub7.Text + " nvarchar(50), Image image, Classification nvarchar(50), Average nvarchar(50), Adviser nvarchar(50), Contact nvarchar(50))", connection);
    MessageBox.Show("Table has been created!");
}
```

Is there any problem with my code?

PS: I already tried with the same/similar topic and it doesn't work and appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should execute your command to see a result.

Add this part before your message box:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: ye, i forgot this.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you mentioned the `Initial catalog` name in the connection string?

Give your **database** name as **`Initial Catalog`** name. Like this in `web.config`:

```
<add name ="AutoRepairSqlProvider" 
     connectionString="Data Source=USER-PC; Initial Catalog=StudentDB; Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
```

One more thing put your code in `try catch` block like this

```
 try
 {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC; Initial Catalog=StudentDB; Integrated Security=True;");
        connection.Open();    
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + txtName.Text + " (LRN int, FirstName nvarchar(50), MiddleName nvarchar(50), LastName nvarchar(50), Gendernvarchar(50), " + txtSub1.Text + " nvarchar(50), " + txtSub2.Text + " nvarchar(50), " + txtSub3.Text + " nvarchar(50), " + txtSub4.Text + " nvarchar(50), " + txtSub5.Text + " nvarchar(50), " + txtSub6.Text + " nvarchar(50), " + txtSub7.Text + " nvarchar(50), Image image, Classification nvarchar(50), Average nvarchar(50), Adviser nvarchar(50), Contact nvarchar(50))", connection);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       MessageBox.Show("Table has been created!");
}
catch(exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("error");
}
```

so that you will get exception or error that will help to understand problem